# Onclick of checkbox not working Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

I am enabling 3 text boxes on checked checkbox and disabling them on uncheck checkbox, but dont know why the code is not working. By default they are disabled with unchecked checkbox.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="input-order-status">
        <?php echo "Modify Default Package Dimensions:"; ?>
    </label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input class="form-control" type="checkbox" name="Modify_Default_Dimensions" value="1" onclick="checkboxChecked(this);">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="input-order-status">
        <?php echo "Depth:"; ?>
    </label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input class="form-control hide_textbox" type="text" id="prod_depth" class="" name="dhl_product_depth" value="12" disabled/> cm
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="input-order-status">
        <?php echo "Width:"; ?>
    </label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input class="form-control hide_textbox" type="text" id="prod_width" name="dhl_product_width" value="34" disabled/> cm
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="input-order-status">
        <?php echo "Height:"; ?>
    </label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input class="form-control hide_textbox" type="text" id="prod_height" name="dhl_product_height" value="123" disabled/> cm
    </div>
</div>
```

```js
function checkboxChecked(clickedBox) {
    var textbox_hide = document.getElementsByClassName('hide_textbox');
    //alert(textbox_hide.length);
    for(var i = 0; i < textbox_hide.length; i++) {
        textbox_hide[i].disabled = !clickedBox.checked;
    }
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g5de48y6/)

Comment: Your fiddle is not set up right, that would be your first problem. You have the JavaScript section running onload when you should have it marked as body or head. (Click the gear icon)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works fine. The issue is that you have two `class` attributes on the textbox `input` elements so the second one (which contained the class you were looking for) was ignored.

```
<input class="form-control hide_textbox" type="text" id="prod_width" name="dhl_product_width" value="34" disabled/>
```

Note that `class` attribute has two values in the above example.

Your fiddle was also not set up correctly as the JS code needs to be placed in the `<head />` of the document.

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/g5de48y6/1/)

Comment: Thanks alot my bad :(